# Is there a dock available that can dock an iPhone (with bumper)

Tags: iphone, hardware-recommendation, dock

The Apple dock cannot take the bumper, you need to take off the bumper.

I need a dock for work and at work where I can just slip my phone in (bumper and all).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon sells a dock from Oriongadget](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003U0PESU) which will allow you to dock an iPhone with his bumper. It will cost you $23.00.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably, not due to the large variation possible with iPhone cases it would be difficult for a exact fit to a specific dock you would almost nead a special dock for each case out there.

The good news is that there is a very good compromise solution and that is a dock connector extension that will allow the iPhone and case to be raised out of the dock and clear most obstructions with most cases and iPhone / iPod docks.  Something such as the [Dock Extender by SendStation](http://www.sendstation.com/us/products/dockextender/) should do what you want.

[image: DockExtender by Sendstation in action]